# tasks and dependencies in Play! framework 2.3

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to do a task in Play! just like that:

in build.sbt

```
lazy val helloTask = TaskKey[Unit]("hello", "description bla bla")

helloTask := {
  mypakage.Myclass.update
  println("well done")
}

(compile in Compile) <<= (compile in Compile)  dependsOn helloTask
```

but when I execute

```
$ activator tasks
```

It doesn't show my "hello" task but runs

```
$ activator hello
```

The problem is when I add references to another classes (mypakage.Myclass.update in the example isn't found)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Despite what the documentation says, I can't seem to list a `TaskKey`, either. But it works with an `InputKey` instead of a `TaskKey`.

```
lazy val helloTask = InputKey[Unit]("hello", "description bla bla")

helloTask := {
  println("well done")
}
```

The other problem is that dependencies in `build.sbt` need to be resolved via sbt plugins. So `mypakage.Myclass` must be split into a separate project in order to be used in another build.

Comment: I have tested to access from a task to [plugin](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaPlugins) and it doesn't run

Comment: What do you mean? I'm talking about sbt plugins: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Using-Plugins.html